# Issue with linkbutton in radlistview

Tags: asp.net

I create a radlistview and bind it with  objectdatasource and define a linkbutton in radlistview
and  linkbutton text bind to multi column in radlistview to display multi line in my radlisview.

Now I want when a user click on linkbutton, **one** row of radlistview that user clicked on is set to a session so I could use it in other pages.

I define selected items in radlistview itemdatabound event or in radlistview itemcommand event, but these events not fire .please help me.
my code is:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbl1" runat="server" 
  OnClick="linqbutton1_Click"
  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
     Text='<%#"&nbsp;&raquo;"+"buy"+" "+Eval("MelkType")+" "+Eval("MelkSize")+" meter"+" "+Eval("Melkregion") %>'
    style="margin-right:0px;direction:rtl;margin-top:20px; ">
  </asp:LinkButton>

<br />
<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="RentalApartmentGet" TypeName="mymelkclass">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just extract the values server side after the selection is made, i think this is demo is close to what you need : 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/selecting/defaultcs.aspx